# how to map an input document field to the elasticsearch _id field?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a fairly simple pipeline for taking json messages from Kafka and sending them to Elasticsearch:

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers =>  "kafka04-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka05-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka03-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093"
        topics => [ "transactions_load" ]
    }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  mutate{
    remove_field => ["kafka"]
    remove_field => ["@version"]
    remove_field => ["@timestamp"]
    remove_field => ["message"]
    remove_tag => ["multiline"]
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [
                "xxxxx.ibm-343.composedb.com:16915",
                "xxxxx.ibm-343.composedb.com:16915"
            ]
        ssl => true
        user => "logstash_kafka"
        password => "*****"
        index => "pos_transactions"
    }
}
```

The json records have a `TransactionID` field that uniquely identifies each record:

```
{"TransactionID": "5440772161", "InvoiceNo": 5440772, "StockCode": 22294, "Description": "HEART FILIGREE DOVE  SMALL", "Quantity": 4, "InvoiceDate": 1507777440000, "UnitPrice": 1.25, "CustomerID": 14825, "Country": "United Kingdom", "LineNo": 16, "InvoiceTime": "03:04:00", "StoreID": 1}
{"TransactionID": "5440772191", "InvoiceNo": 5440772, "StockCode": 21733, "Description": "RED HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER", "Quantity": 4, "InvoiceDate": 1507777440000, "UnitPrice": 2.95, "CustomerID": 14825, "Country": "United Kingdom", "LineNo": 19, "InvoiceTime": "03:04:00", "StoreID": 1}
```

Can I configure logstash to use the `TransactionID` as the `_id` field so that if I process duplicate records for the same transaction, these updates are idempotent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out myself.  Posting here because it may be useful for others:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [
                "xxxxx.ibm-343.composedb.com:16915",
                "xxxxx.ibm-343.composedb.com:16915"
            ]
        ssl => true
        user => "logstash_kafka"
        password => "*****"
        index => "pos_transactions"
        document_id => "%{TransactionID}"
    }
}
```

The `document_id => "%{TransactionID}"` configuration entry uses the incoming document `TransactionID` field for the elasticsearch `_id`